# Is it possible to disable other applications within an app

Tags: ios

Had a question regarding security in iOS, is it possible to disable an app from another app? I'm aware Apple strives for security and not allowing other apps to change the behavior of other applications, but just wondering if it would be possible at all to do something like this? By disable I mean just temporarily not being able to use, not removing it

Comment: Maybe by some Apple library?, I'm aware Apple has issues with 3rd party libraries being used when deploying to the app store

Comment: Short answer: not possible

Answer (score 1):

Not possible from other app. Only way from settings -> General -> Restrictions

[image]